# How to start an Alfresco Workflow through HTML forms

Tags: html, alfresco, activiti

I need to start an Activity workflow from an external HTML form (outside activiti). I do not want to use the form that Activiti provides.

I am using Alfresco Activiti BPM Suite v1.4.0. Any pointers ?

Comment: What do you mean by "calling an external form to start a workflow". please describe your system.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question....i don't want to use the forms which are available within the Alfresco Activiti BPM Suite v1.4.0. I want to create my own html forms. The html forms should be able to trigger a workflow in alfresco activiti. Any pointers as to how this can be done ??

Comment: Are you using only activiti or you have also alfresco?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running activiti in Alfresco, you can implement a webscript that will receive the post of your form and will start the task.

If you are running a standalone Activiti, you can use the activiti REST api. 
I do not have code to share but the documentation should be enough to get started.

You can find a good example at: [Rest API](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_rest_support)

This makes use of Spring Boot. In practice, you can develop your REST API that starts the process and then you can call the service directly from the browser using Ajax, or post to your application and execute the REST call from there.

To be honest, I have never done it, but it seems a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks Marco for all the help !! I will be using the Activiti REST API for triggering the workflows from external forms. I am sorry but the documentation aren't that helpful.

Comment: @Sunita Nayak, did you manage to solve your problem? If so, could you please provide some sample implementation?